# how to uninstall JDK on centos x64 linux based system

Tags: centos, java, centos5, uninstall

I tried installing JDK in my CentOS x64 web server, it looks like I have made a hash of things :(...

Now, how do I uninstall JDK 1.6.0_26 in Centos x64 linux?

Regards,
Arvind.

Comment: Did you install openjdk from yum or Oracle JDK?

Comment: i installed using yum...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried `yum remove jdk`?

Comment: @Arvind Be sure to accept the answer if it fixed your problem. That's how ServerFault and the rest of the Stackexchange network works